# Which is this product's product type?

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, product-type

Need to find out product type and create it in magento 2

check image - https://prnt.sc/rsrc42

Comment: so type means simple virtual downloadable configuare etc . ? you want to get this type ?

Comment: i want to know , the product in the image is of which product type and how can i create this product in magento 2 ?

Comment: This could be a simple product with options. Take a look here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a configurable product with simple products